# Angular 7 ngFor iterate over array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't iterate over an array of objects. In each object, I have a name, but I can't get the text of the object or the name inside it.

I have the following code in my ts file

```
retrieveMultiple(config, "accounts")
.then(
    (results) => {
        const accounts: any[] = [];
        for (let record of results.value) {
            accounts.push(record);
        }

        this.accounts= accounts;
        console.log(accounts[0].name);
        console.log(accounts);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

And I have this in my HTML file:

```
      <p>Accounts:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let account of accounts | json">
      {{ account.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why are you using the json pipe?

Comment: why do you need json pipe here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have the `json` pipe in your loop expression. Change your output code to this:

```html
<p>Accounts:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let account of accounts">
    {{ account.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

or for debugging you could use this:

```html
<p>Accounts:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let account of accounts">
    {{ account | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

```
retrieveMultiple(config, "accounts")
.then(
    (results) => {
        this.accounts = results.value;
        console.log(this.accounts[0].name);
        console.log(this.accounts);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
)
```

```html
<p>Accounts:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let account of accounts">
    {{ account.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have   accounts = []; so account.value will not work

Comment: Then it will not display anything inside the <ul>